# Changing text dynamically, how to not remove the <i> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this button:

```
<button disabled="" id="btnGuardarPaso1" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
```

And then through jQuery I change the text dynamically based on user selection on a select element. See the code:

```
if (tipoTramiteSolVal != 1 && tipoTramiteSolVal !== "" && tipoTramiteSolVal != undefined ) {
    $("#btnGuardarPaso1").removeClass("btn-primary").text("Edit");
} else {
    $("#btnGuardarPaso1").addClass("btn-primary").text("Save");
}
```

But, this code has a problem: the `<i class="fa fa-save"></i>` element is also removed/changed and I'll like to maintain it. How I can fix this?

Also since the button has a FontAwesome icon, can I change it dynamically too? For example `fa-save` will change for `fa-edit` and viceversa depending on the choice by user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a span tag inside of the button and set the text of the span rather than the button.  The italics would then be outside of the span.

```
<button disabled="" id="btnGuardarPaso1" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"><span id="textItem"></span></i> Save</button>


if (tipoTramiteSolVal != 1 && tipoTramiteSolVal !== "" && tipoTramiteSolVal != undefined ) {
$("#btnGuardarPaso1").removeClass("btn-primary");
$("#textItem").text("Edit");
} else {
$("#btnGuardarPaso1").addClass("btn-primary");
$("#textItem").text("Save");
}
```

[edit] also if you use jQuery to look up the italic tag (either directly by ID or by traversing the DOM) you can definitely set the class using:

```
 $(this).attr('class','classname');
```

Comment: Not my final solution but I take your idea and build my own by adding a `<span>` and modifying my code as `$("#btnGuardarPaso1").removeClass("btn-primary").find('span').text("Edit");` just the FA part I don't know how to do it

Comment: @lukevp not sure why you used an id instead of just doing `$("#btnGuardarPaso1").removeClass("btn-primary").find("span").text("Edit");`

Comment: @ReynierPM `toggleClass()`

Comment: @epascarello what you mean with `toggleClass()`? Can you put an example here?

Comment: Um, just like how text is changed, fiond the element and add/remove the classes. $("#btnGuardarPaso1").find("i").toggleClass("fa-save fa-edit");

Comment: @epascarello have to use in this way instead `$("#btnGuardarPaso1").find('i').removeClass('fa-save').addClass('fa-edit');` because `toggleClass` change it all the time and this is not what I want